# SARSA update rule

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

The update rule for the SARSA algorithm, which is mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State%E2%80%93action%E2%80%93reward%E2%80%93state%E2%80%93action) is the following.

$Q(s_t,a_t) \leftarrow Q(s_t,a_t) + \alpha [r_{t+1} + \gamma Q(s_{t+1}, a_{t+1})-Q(s_t,a_t)]$

My question is, why can't the value functions be used in the RHS of the update rather than choosing a sample action? In other words, why can't the update be as follows?

$Q(s_t,a_t) \leftarrow Q(s_t,a_t) + \alpha [r_{t+1} + \gamma V(s_{t+1})-Q(s_t,a_t)]$

Will this update rule work? If it does, what advantage does the SARSA update have over this update rule?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with what Sean said. I'll add this little bit to answer this question you asked more concretely:

> Will this update rule work? If it does, what advantage does the SARSA update have over this update rule?

The SARSA update rule can converge to different values than the Q-learning rule (which is, like Sean said, essentially what you suggested). This is due to the difference between on-policy and off-policy that he also described. An on-policy algorithm (like the SARSA update rule) converges to the optimal values for the policy that your agent is also using to gather experience. Off-policy algorithms converge to values for a policy that is different from the policy being followed by the agent to gather experience.

The behaviour policy (the one that the agent uses to gather experience) is typically going to be something like $\epsilon$-greedy, where with some nonzero probability you select suboptimal (random) actions. An on-policy algorithm like SARSA takes this into account, it converges to values that are still correct given the knowledge that your agent is sometimes going to be "stupid" and do something random. Q-learning (off-policy learning with a pure greedy policy as "target policy", the policy you're computing values for) is going to converge to values that are actually only going to be correct later on, when your agent switches over to a completely greedy policy.

This distinction can, for example, be important in situations where you care about learning "safe" behaviour during the learning process, where you don't just care about learning optimal behaviour to run after the learning process. Suppose, for example, that you have a robot who starts near a cliff, and needs to walk to another point along the same cliff.

- A Q-learning algorithm is going to converge to values that tell the agent that it's optimal to walk right along the cliff, because that's the shortest path.
- SARSA is going to converge to different values, which will tell the agent that it's optimal to first walk a safe distance away from the cliff, and then move towards the goal, only getting close to the cliff again when also being close to the destination. It will converge to these values because it knows of itself that it will sometimes be stupid and take a random action. If it happens to be close to the cliff when it takes a random action, it will fall down and you have to buy a new robot which can be very expensive. So, it will learn (because it's learning values for the $\epsilon$-greedy policy) that the optimal behaviour is to first walk away from the cliff, so that it won't fall even if it sometimes takes a random action.

Answer (score 2):

It one sense, it can: Your second equation is the update rule for Q-learning. (See the definitions in Ch. 6 of Sutton and Barto's [draft edition](http://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/~straka/courses/npfl114/2016/sutton-bookdraft2016sep.pdf) of *Reinforcement Learning*, along with the relation $V(S) = \max_a Q(S,a)$. I don't have a written source for this at hand, but it's covered in early sections of [this course](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud600).)

The major difference is that SARSA is **on-policy**: It learns the $Q$ values of the policy that it's following. Off-policy learners, Q-learning included, improve a policy different from that used to generate the data.

Here's a summary the differing advantages between on- and off-policy, again from Sutton and Barto:

> On-policy methods are generally simpler and are considered first. Off-policy methods require additional concepts and notation, and because the data is due to a different policy, off-policy methods are often of greater variance and are slower to converge. On the other hand, off-policy methods are more powerful and general. They include on-policy methods as the special case in which the target and behavior policies are the same. Off-policy methods also have a variety of additional uses in applications. For example, they can often be applied to learn from data generated by a conventional non-learning controller, or from a human expert.

Ch. 6 of the draft, very much worth a read, also includes a comparison of SARSA and Q-learning from several perspectives, to include performance on an example and conditions for convergence to the optimal policy.

Comment: $v_{\pi}(s)$ and $v_{*}(s)$ are both options for value function as OP has written it. The former, $v_{\pi}(s)$  is to me a more natural reading of OP's suggested formula, since it would be odd to have $q_{\pi}(s, a)$ evaluation of current policy from SARSA being estimated alongside a maximising state value function. In that case, the suggested algorithm could be *Expected SARSA*, which is also off-policy, but has some interesting pros and cons compared to SARSA or Q-Learning.